# Variable changes value

Tags: c++, enums, sdl

my problem is bunch of variables, that increase themselfs during program's work, which, of course shouldn't ever happen. Here is code with explanation (this A LOT of code, so if you got some suggestions how to shorten it, will be thankful), this is game Mastermind, and the idea of this whole code im struggling with right now, is case, when you can't pick 2 same colors at one time, so if you click the button, it will skip all taken colours all the way towards next not taken color (this MOUSE_BUTTON_UP_[color] is enum type, if its important):

```
void Button::handleEvent( SDL_Event* e)
{
int Switch=0;
int sprite=0;
int temp = 0;
//If mouse event happened
if( e->type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION || e->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN || e->type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP )
{
    //Get mouse position
    int x, y;
    SDL_GetMouseState( &x, &y );

    //Check if mouse is in button
    bool inside = true;

    //Mouse is left of the button
    if( x < mPosition.x )
    {
        inside = false;
    }
    //Mouse is right of the button
    else if( x > mPosition.x + globals::BUTTON_WIDTH )
    {
        inside = false;
    }
    //Mouse above the button
    else if( y < mPosition.y )
    {
        inside = false;
    }
    //Mouse below the button
    else if( y > mPosition.y + globals::BUTTON_HEIGHT )
    {
        inside = false;
    }
    if(inside)
    {
        switch (e->type)
        {
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            Switch = Button::switchingBalls();
            sprite = Button::getCurrentSprite();
            if(sprite == 8)
                mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_RED;
            if(Switch + sprite > 7)
            {
                temp = 7 - sprite;
                switch (temp)
                {
                case 1:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_GREY;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_DBLUE;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_VIOLET;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_RED;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            if(Switch == 0)
            {
                switch (sprite)
                {                   
                case 0:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_VIOLET;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_DBLUE;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_GREY;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_DGREEN;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LBLUE;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LGREEN;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_YELLOW;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if(Switch == 1)
            {
                switch(sprite)
                {
                case 0:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_DBLUE;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_GREY;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_DGREEN;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LBLUE;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LGREEN;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_YELLOW;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_RED;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if(Switch == 2)
            {
                switch(sprite)
                {
                case 0:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_GREY;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_DGREEN;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LBLUE;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LGREEN;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_YELLOW;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_RED;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_VIOLET;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if(Switch == 3)
            {
                switch(sprite)
                {
                case 0:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_DGREEN;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LBLUE;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LGREEN;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_YELLOW;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_RED;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_VIOLET;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_DBLUE;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if(Switch == 4)
            {
                switch(sprite)
                {
                case 0:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LBLUE;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LGREEN;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_YELLOW;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_RED;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_VIOLET;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_DBLUE;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_GREY;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Button::switchingBalls() doesnt really matter, there is no problem.
Button::getCurrentSprite() returns currently selected color (it's value in int from enum type).

Now, i got 4 objects of class "Button" in main, for each object in I check if something changes (someone clicks it) and then whole code above happens.
But, not matter which color is currently selected (class constructor defined to RED by default to all), it always changes to YELLOW.
What is even more intresting, when i toggle watches, and try to figure out what happens, it all works fine. If i set breakpoint to this line:

```
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_RED;
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            if(Switch == 0)//breakpoint goes here
            {
                switch (sprite)
                {                   
                case 0:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_VIOLET;
```

Everything is ok, it works fine ('sprite' value is 0). But if I set breakpoint to this line:

```
                    case 5:
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_LGREEN;
                    break;
                case 6://breakpoint goes here
                    mCurrentSprite = BUTTON_SPRITE_MOUSE_UP_YELLOW;
                    break;
```

everything goes crazy. 'sprite' value suddenly increases to 6. What's even more crazy, when i set breakpoint before 'case 5', 'case 4' etc. it happens all the same, but the values then is 5 and 4.

Can someone tell me, what the hell is wrong with this thing, couse im really desperate. I have no other idea, how to programm this, or what is wrong. HELP!

Comment: "Variable changes value": Easily the best title I've seen all day ;)

Comment: I believe the whole code can be replaced with something like `mCurrentSprite = (Switch + sprite) % 7`.

Comment: Along with what @AntonSavin suggested, the code can be simplified. Maybe that can solve your problem.

Comment: If you find the value of `sprite` suddenly changes when you set a different breakpoint, you may simply be looking at different times the function is called - as a hack, try creating a global variable and incrementing it at the beginning of `void Button::handleEvent(SDL_Event*)` to see which call you're in.

Comment: "Variable changes value" - That's what it is meant for!

Answer (score 0):

remove
`int sprite=0;`

and change
`sprite = Button::getCurrentSprite();`
to
`const int sprite = Button::getCurrentSprite();`
and see where this takes you

Comment: unfortunately, nowhere. it didn't helped at all.